# How can I have a common test suite for multiple packages in go?

Tags: go

When I'm writing an interface, its often convenient to define my tests in the same package as the interface, and then define multiple packages that implement the interface set, eg.

```
package/
package/impl/x <-- Implementation X
package/impl/y <-- Implementation Y
```

Is there an easy way to run the same test suite (in this case, located in `package/*_test.go`) in the sub packages?

The best solution I've come up with so far is to add a test package:

```
package/tests/
```

Which implements the test suite, and a test in each of the implementations to run the tests, but this has two downsides:

1) The tests in `package/tests` are not in `_test.go` files, and end up being part of the actual library, documented by `godoc`, etc.

2) The tests in `package/tests` are run by a custom test runner, which has to basically duplicate all the functionality of `go test` to scan for go tests and run them.

Seems like a pretty tacky solution.

Is there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't really dislike the idea to use a separate testing library. If you have an interface and you have generic tests for each interface, other people that implement that interface might like to use these tests as well.

You could create a package `"package/test"` that contains a function

```
// functions needed for each implementation to test it
type Tester struct {
    func New() package.Interface
    func (*package.Interface) Done()
    // whatever you need. Leave nil if function does not apply
}

func TestInterface(t *testing.T, tester Tester)
```

Notice that the signature of `TestInterface` does not match to what `go test` expects. Now, for each package `package/impl/x` you add one file `generic_test.go`:

```
package x

import "testing"
import "package/test"

// run generic tests on this particular implementation
func TestInterface(t *testing.T) {
    test.TestInterface(t,test.Tester{New:New})
}
```

Where `New()` is the constructor function of your implementation. The advantage with this scheme is that

1. Your tests are reusable for whoever implements your interface, even from other packages
2. It is immediately obvious that you run the generic test suite
3. The test cases are where the implementation is and not at another, obscure place
4. The code can be adapted easily if one implementation needs special initialization or similar stuff
5. It's `go test` compatible (big plus!)

Of course, in some cases you need a more complicated `TestInterface` function, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what I'm doing (using var args to let the impl supply a setup and teardown function if it wants); like I said though, it's a bit annoying to have the functions  turn up in generated go doc output, and having one 'mega test' that runs all the sub tests make 'go test' hang for ages on that one item (I agree with all your other points tho).

Comment: @Doug I prefer to use a struct for auxilliary functions and data; it's much cleaner and you can supply nil (the default value for pointers) if there is no such function. Also, you might want to strip some tests if [testing.Short()](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Short) is set and strip some test cases if that is the case.

Comment: @Doug BTW, what's the point that the testing functions show up in the documentation? You can move them to another package (as I suggested) if they clutter up the documentation.

Comment: @FUZxxi I tend to use go doc ./... to generate my docs; obviously that includes the test package.

Answer (score 1):

If you share a piece of code for reuse by different packages then yes, it is a library by definition. Even when used only for testing from *_test.go files. It's no different from importing "testing" of "fmt" in the _test.go file. And having the API documented by godoc is a plus, not minus IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something gets mixed up here a bit:
If package a defines an interface only than there is no code to
test as interfaces in Go are implementation free.

So I assume the methods in your interface in package a
have constraints. E.g. in

```
interface Walker {
    Walk(step int)
    Tired() bool
}
```

you contract assumes that Tired returns true if more than
500 steps have been Walk'ed (and false otherwise)
and your test code checks these dependencies
(or assumption, contracts, invariants whatever you
name it).

If this is the case I would provide (in package a) an exported
function

```
func TestWalkerContract(w Walker) error {
    w.Walk(100)
    if w.Tired() { return errors.New("Tired after 100 steps") }
    w.Walk(450)
    if !w.Tired() { return errors.New("Not tired after 100+450 steps") }
}
```

Which documents the contract properly and can be used by packages
b and c with types implementing walker to test their implementations
in b_test.go and c_test.go. IMHO it is perfectly okay that these
function like TestWalkerContract are displayed by godoc.

P.S. More common than Walk and Tired might be an error state
which is kept and reported until cleared/reseted.